# Java FXML - TableView not displaying data

Tags: java, fxml

My TableView is not displaying the data that it gets from the database. It displays the first column but no other. While debugging, i can see the ArrayList it receives is filled with the data, and the data i'm trying to display is a String, an int and a Timestamp.

I have used this kind of code all over my program, but for some reason, it won't work on this particular screen.

Here's the FXML:

```
    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="331.0" prefWidth="340.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="desomer_michael_vivesbike.Controllers.RittenOverzichtController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Ritten">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TableView fx:id="lijst_ritten" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="312.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Ritnr">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="id" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Lid">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="lidNaam" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Fiets">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="fietsNr" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="85.0" text="Begindatum">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="startTijd" />
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button layoutX="15.0" layoutY="253.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toRitToevoegScherm" text="Toevoegen" />
      <Button layoutX="99.0" layoutY="253.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Wijzigen" />
      <Button layoutX="170.0" layoutY="253.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Verwijderen" />
      <Button layoutX="257.0" layoutY="253.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Afsluiten" />
      <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="289.0" textFill="RED">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="287.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toHoofdscherm" text="Terug" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And here is the code that fills the TableView from the controller:

```
public void getAlleRitten(){
        try{
            RitTrans ritTrans = new RitTrans();
            ArrayList<Rit> lijst = ritTrans.getAlleRitten();
            lijst_ritten.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(ritTrans.getAlleRitten()));
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Fout in RittenOverzichtController.getAlleRitten(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The objects in the ArrayList that is received from getAlleRitten() are objects from the class Rit, here are its fields:

```
public class Rit {
private int id;
private Timestamp startTijd;
private Timestamp eindTijd;
private Fiets fiets;
private Lid lid;
private String lidNaam;
private int fietsNr;
private int prijs;
private ArrayList<String> opmerkingen;

public Rit(int id, Timestamp startTijd, Timestamp eindTijd) {
    this.id = id;
    this.startTijd = startTijd;
    this.eindTijd = eindTijd;
}

public Rit(){

}

public int getPrijs() {
    return prijs;
}

public void setPrijs(int prijs) {
    this.prijs = prijs;
}

public ArrayList<String> getOpmerkingen() {
    return opmerkingen;
}

public void setOpmerkingen(ArrayList<String> opmerkingen) {
    this.opmerkingen = opmerkingen;
}

public Lid getLid() {
    return lid;
}

public void setLid(Lid lid) {
    this.lid = lid;
    lidNaam = lid.getNaam() + " " + lid.getVoornaam();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Timestamp getStartTijd() {
    return startTijd;
}

public void setStartTijd(Timestamp startTijd) {
    this.startTijd = startTijd;
}

public Timestamp getEindTijd() {
    return eindTijd;
}

public void setEindTijd(Timestamp eindTijd) {
    this.eindTijd = eindTijd;
}

public Fiets getFiets() {
    return fiets;
}

public void setFiets(Fiets fiets) {
    this.fiets = fiets;
    fietsNr = fiets.getRegisNr();
}
```

}
An example screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, it fills in the first column just fine, but everything else not.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: i got the column "beginDatum" working, one of the letters was capitalized and i didn't see that, but the middle 2 columns still don't work.

Comment: The getters and setters matter.  What do yours look like?  Does your data model conform to the specification for a Java FX bean?  It needs to have a property getter.  Moreover, your fields also need to be Java FX properties (which are observable) and not simple primitive or non-FX types.

Comment: i've added the getters and setters. And sorry, but i don't know what you mean with "data model conform to the specification for a java FX bean", i'm only a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Your data model does not appear to conform to the specifics needed for Java FX.  Here is an example of a data model that works fine in an FX tableview:

```
public class Client extends DB {

    private final long      m_appUID;

    private IntegerProperty id =         new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private LongProperty    defmrnKey =  new SimpleLongProperty();
    private StringProperty  lastName =   new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty  midName =    new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty  firstName =  new SimpleStringProperty();
    private IntegerProperty doB =        new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private StringProperty  gender =     new SimpleStringProperty();



    public final int getID() {return this.id.get(); }
    void setID(int id) { this.id.set(id); }
    public final IntegerProperty idProperty() { return this.id; }

    public final long getDefMRNKey() { return this.defmrnKey.get(); }
    public final void setDefMRNKey(long id) { this.defmrnKey.set(id); }
    public final LongProperty defMRNKeyProperty() { return this.defmrnKey; }

    :
    :
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i appreciate the answer though. But i've used tableviews a few times now in my program, and i've always filled them like i showed in my original post, this is the only one giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The `property` value that you set in the `PropertyValueFactory` must match the noun portion of your getter in order for reflection to find it. For instance, your example shows

```
<cellValueFactory>
  <PropertyValueFactory property="lidNaam" />
</cellValueFactory>
```

so your getter should be

```
getLidNaam()
```

However, you have

```
getLid()
```

which won't be found by reflection. Update your getters to use the correct noun value assigned to each property.

The information provided by @scottb is also correct. If you ever want to be able to edit values inside your `TableView` then you'll need to use the `*Property()` methods in order to do so. Take a look at the Java [TableView tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm), specifically the DataModel section.